# How to show a div when Click on text box in asp.net. using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I tried like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#divID').hide();
 $('#txtInsertComments').Onfocus(function () {
 $('#divID').show();    });
});
</script>


//Asp.net Design
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertComments" runat="server" Text="Demo"></asp:TextBox>
   <div runat="server" id="divID">
This is Div
</div>
```

but still not working... please help me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this with `Master Page` then the ID of your `Textbox` will change.So use this.

```
$('<%txtInsertComments.ClientID%>').focus(function () {
     $('#divID').show();    });
    });
```

If you are not using `Master Page` then this should work

```
$('#txtInsertComments.ClientID').focus(function () {
         $('#divID').show();    });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. I am using Master Page. I did the same but still not working.. :( I can see div containt on my page before click on Text Box

Comment: @SonamMohite How can you see the div , are you not hiding it in your document.ready function.